# Show that this Galois group is solvable (Base case)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, kummer-theory

So I've been reading a proof of

Theorem : If E/K is a normal and radical field extension then Gal(E/K) is a solvable group.

The author then goes on a proof by induction but he shrugs off the base case saying it's trivial, while I've been trying to understand it.

Statement : If $ E = K(a_1, ..., a_n) / K $ is radical then Gal(E/K) is solvable for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $

Base case : Let's show that $ E = K(a)/K $ is radical implies Gal(E/K) is solvable.

Without loss of generality we can suppose that $ p $ such that $, \; \: a^p \in K $ is prime.

If K contains the p-th roots of unity, then it follows that K(a)/K is a Kummer extension ( generated by the p-th root a )  and so Gal(E/K) is a cyclic group, so it's abelian which means it is solvable.

But my issue is that we don't have any hypothesis on whether K contains the p-th roots of unity or not. So how do we go about proving that Gal(E/K) is still an abelian group? We know that E/K is normal so the p-th roots of unity will be found in E.

Comment: Can you not use $E = K$ as a base case?

Comment: Adjoin units and pass to the higher Galois group.

Comment: Ravi >  the author says  " for n= 1" it's obvious x) 



Dan_fuela > It seems that's what they do later on in the proof, but the base case is supposed to be quick, how do you pass to a higher group? Gal(K(a)/K) < Gal(K(a)/L)?

Comment: As the proof itsef is pretty long, yes perhaps the author meant E = K is obvious : and I would agree with that! Thanks

Comment: For the n=1 case, you can adjoin all the pth roots of unity and get an abelian extension. Then adjoin a and the composition of abelian extensions will still be abelian. This is basically what dan is saying.

Comment: What's the relation between the abelian Galois group  of the composition Gal(L(a)/L) and Gal(K(a)/K) then? 

It seems we need quotient groups to get Gal(K(a)/K) solvable and that's similar to the detailled induction step.

Comment: Adjoin the $p$-th roots to get abelian extension, adjoin $p$-th root $a$ to that to get an abelian extension of the first, so the result is solvable extension of $K$.

Comment: Actually whether or not K contains the roots of unity,  K(a^{1/p} ) is cyclic thus abelian.  

Sorry I thought we needed more conditions to apply the "Kummer extension implies cyclic"  proposition.